# Complex object serialization

Tags: java, android, serialization

I've got a few questions on the topic of serializing complex objects and writing them to a file.

First, I've got a few objects which are connected to each other, in more precise ways I have an object which holds another objects in a list which are also holding another object. so, the overall architecture of the object I want to write to the file looks as follows:

```
ComplexObject
-> holds List of NotSoComplexObject(s)
--> every NotSoComplexObject
---> holds a SimpleObject
```

all of the objects implement the Serializable interface.

if I try to serialize the ComplexObject and write it to a file I got no specific Exception as the 
    Exception.getMessage() 
method returns NULL (so, it's an Exception that is being thrown, but it's not clear which Exception it is).

Is there a way to achieve the ComplexObject to be serialized and stored in a file?

Comment: An exception can have no message and still be interesting, you need to know its definitive type. Try `exception.printStackTrace()`, and paste the full stack trace in your question, that'll help understand what's going on.

Comment: thanks a lot - I got a "NoSuchMethodException" in my DDMS (Android Debugging Tool for Eclipse), seems it's connected to the GeoPoint I try to serialize with the whole bunch of objects... 

I'm confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception itself tells you what type it is. I assume its NotSerializableException.

In Java you might do...

```
System.err.println(e);
e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: thanks for your quick replies! 

actually it is something I didn't expect it to be in any way, it's a "NoSuchMethodException" and it seems that it is thrown from the GeoPoint object I'm trying to save with the whole bunch of things!

is this really possible? and if so, how would I solve this problem? I'm actually never had something like this before so I'm a little bit lost... is there any problem with the Android Manifest.xml or something like that??

Comment: NoSuchMethodException means the library attempted to lookup a method at runtime which wasn't available.  It means either your library has a bug in it or you haven't configured it correctly. I would attempt to get support from the provider of the library.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I appreciate it a lot!

Actually I resolved the problem by following these 2 steps:

1.)
Create your own GeoPoint class which should extend GeoPoint and implement Serializable as the GeoPoint object itself is not implementing the Serializable interface. ///// 
2.)
Adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>` to the Manifest, as well as the `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` entry

Comment: Make sure if you are using a inner/anonymous/nested class it is `static` otherwise the outer class will be serialized as well.